# each array and set atributte X times

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have a array with some objects:

`var myArray = [{name: "Elliot", type: "person"},{name: "ET", type: "ufo"},{name: "Mary", type: "person"},{name: "AEI", type: "ufo"}]`

I want each this and set X time other type, this times are set in other variables.

`var type1 = 2;`

`var type2 = 1;`

`var type3 = 3;`

I try with:

`for( i = 0; i < type1 ; i ++){ myArray.set({type:'no-et'})}`

`for( i = 0; i < type2 ; i ++){ myArray.set({type:'is-no-et'})}`

`for( i = 0; i < type3 ; i ++){ myArray.set({type:'is-no-et-4'})}`

But only works the first time, but not others because I each again the same array, but not have a idea how each array and set type X times only and then each again and set X times without losing what was done before.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: _"I want each this and set X time other type, this times are set in other variables"_ Not certain gather requirement correctly. What is expected result?

Comment: the expect result, if my array length is 4 and my type variables as: `var type1 = 2; var type2 = 1; var type3 = 2;` my array variable at the end must be `[{name: "Elliot", type: "no-et"},{name: "ET", type: "no-et"},{name: "Mary", type: "is-no-et"},{name: "AEI", type: "is-no-et-4"}]`

Comment: This question has nothing to do with backbone. Please use proper tags while posting questions

Comment: for set my type's I use "set for assing data to my attributes in backbone  collection, for this I tagged backbone too. But I'll keep it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try coming at the problem another way, iterate over the array and check what index you're on to set the type.

```js
var people = [
    { name: "Elliot", type: "person" },
    { name: "ET", type: "ufo" },
    { name: "Mary", type: "person" },
    { name: "AEI", type: "ufo" }
];

for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    if (i < 2) {
      people[i].type = "no-et";
    }

    if (i === 2) {
      people[i].type = "is-no-et";
    }

    if (i > 2) {
      people[i].type = "is-no-et-4";
    }
  
    document.write("Name: " + people[i].name + ", Type: " + people[i].type + "<br>");
}
```